# is ThrowIfCancellationRequested really needed when CancellationToken is already passed to time-consuming Async methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

**Hello!**

I was programming a piece of code and a question came up.. In this example, is it really necessary to use ThrowIfCancellationRequested? I mean, the operation that could be considerably time-consuming is GetAsync, the rest is negligible, and since the CancellationToken is passed to it, if it expires, an exception is thrown at that point. Therefore, I don't see that ThrowIfCancellationRequested is essential, although it could be a plus but really insignificant.

```
    public static async Task<string> GetSomething(long id, HttpClient client, CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.yourdomain.es/endpoint/{id}", ct);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        string jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(ct);

        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        
        //Additional logic here

        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

Comment: Only you can decide if it's important or not.

Comment: It's only useful to check `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` if the code that follows that check (or methods that get called after it) are expensive (in time and/or resources) and you want to terminate as quickly as you can.